# onmouseover event is not firing for a table cell

Tags: javascript, jquery

I've problem with onmouseevent for a table cell.
What I'm doing is removing and creating html table cell with the help of jquery. When page loads this event fires perfectly fine. But after removing and inserting table cell again at same position does not fire the onmouseover event. Below is the code what I've done...

```
var ModularAdHolderCell = '';
var MergedCellValues = new Array();
$('#our_table tr').each(function (i, el) {
  for (var cellCnt = 0; cellCnt < this.cells.length; cellCnt++) {
    if ($(this.cells[cellCnt]).attr('class') == 'highlighted' || $(this.cells[cellCnt]).attr('class') == 'OrangeBackground highlighted') {
            var id = $(this.cells[cellCnt]).attr('id');
            ModularAdHolderCell = id;
            id = 'hdn_' + id;
            var MergedCells = $(this.cells[cellCnt]).find('input:hidden').val();
            if (MergedCells != '')
                MergedCellValues = MergedCells.trim().split('=');
        }
    }
});

var row = document.all.our_table.rows[0];
var TotalCellInRow = row.cells.length;
var Cell = row.insertCell(TotalCellInRow);
var element1 = document.createElement("input");
element1.type = "hidden";
element1.id = "hdn_" + MergedCellValues[cnt];

row.cells(TotalCellInRow).setAttribute('onmouseover', 'MOuseOver(this)');
row.cells(TotalCellInRow).setAttribute('onmouseout', 'MouseOut()');
row.cells(TotalCellInRow).setAttribute('onmousemove', 'MOuseOver(this)');
row.cells(TotalCellInRow).setAttribute('onmouseenter', 'MOuseOver(this)');

row.cells(TotalCellInRow).setAttribute('unitheight', Unitwidth);
row.cells(TotalCellInRow).setAttribute('unitwidth', UnitHeight);
row.cells(TotalCellInRow).setAttribute('id', MergedCellValues[cnt]);

row.cells(TotalCellInRow).setAttribute('width', Unitwidth);
row.cells(TotalCellInRow).setAttribute('height', UnitHeight);
row.cells(TotalCellInRow).appendChild(element1);

$(row).find('#' + MergedCellValues[cnt] + '').attr('onmouseover', 'MOuseOver(this)');
$(row).find('#' + MergedCellValues[cnt] + '').attr('onmouseout', 'MouseOut()');
$(row).find('#' + MergedCellValues[cnt] + '').attr('onmousemove', 'MOuseOver(this)');
$(row).find('#' + MergedCellValues[cnt] + '').attr('onmouseenter', 'MOuseOver(this)');
```

Here MergedCellValues is the array of cell id and above code is in the loop of the cell.

Can anyone tell why it does not firing onmouseover event for the cell ?

Comment: @Ronak; for such questions, it's almost always crucial to specify what browser you're testing this on; it might give clues on what's going on.

Comment: What does your `MOuseOver` function look like?

Comment: @BeemerGuy: I'm using IE8. The strange thing is that it's working fine for safari.

Comment: @Ronak Something not working in IE but working fine in a webkit browser isn't strange. IE is the redheaded step-child of the web dev world and it never likes to play nice.

Comment: @Nick Craver: I've one image with info about rows and cell it should occupy when drop on the table cell. So when image is being dropped I get this info and merge table cell according to this info. MOuseOver containts this logic.

Comment: @Ronak - which version of jQuery? you could *greatly* simplify this, how much depends on which version.

Comment: @Glenn Nelson : I completely agree with you....do you have any idea about this problem ?

Comment: @Nick Craver : I'm using jquery-1.4.2

Comment: Ronak when your posting code samples please ensure that they will work. Apart from the missing implementation of MouseOver that Nick pointed out there are also other undeclared objects such as cnt, UnitWidth and UnitHeight. Its easy to figure out what these should be be but its best if you do this for us :) Also a simple same of the html structure your working on would be nice.

Answer (score 1):

Setting an attribute just isn't the intended way to attach an event handler, you can simplify and speed things up an great deal here, remove all of your `.setAttribute('onmouseover', 'MOuseOver(this)');` logic...all 8 lines, then just attach *one* set of handlers to the `<table>` to handle all of this:

```
$("#our_table")
   .delegate("td", "mouseover mousemove mouseenter", MOuseOver)
   .delegate("td", "mouseout", MouseOut);
```

then in your `MOuseOver` and `MouseOut` functions, just use `this` to refer to the cell.

This attaches handlers to the `<table>` element to listen for the other mouse events bubbling up...no need for binding them per-cell, this is *far* less expensive and works on current and new cells combined.

Comment: @Ronak - I updated it since you're on jQuery 1.4.2, the 1.4.3+ syntax wouldn't work you you...the code above should work though, and be sure to use `this` in your functions, instead of the parameter you're passing in now.